# Clicking on span in between text tags using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, automation, element

I want to click on `<span>` tag, by using 'name' element of input type radio.

for below html

```
<label class="mt-radio nomargin-bot">
         <input name="commission_or_margin" value="margin" type="radio">
         Margin
         <span></span>
<label>
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to click on the radio button or something else?

Comment: What is preventing you from doing this?

Comment: Have you left out the contents of the span purposefully or is it empty? Becoz an empty span will have have zero width and unable to be clicked.

Comment: Right now your `<span>` tag contains nothing, so what are you trying to do with `<span>` tag. can you explain here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following-sibling **xpath** function you can achieve this as shown below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='commission_or_margin']/following-sibling::span")).click();
```

Let me know, whether it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Mahipal for quick answer.

Comment: There are two radio button for same 'name' element, so it's didn't work. But yes it working fine by 'id' element.

Comment: Ok great. Could upvote if you found this answer useful and/or accept if it has answered your question, in order to close this thread?